# Pages made with Visual Composer is overlapped over the footer of existing wordpress themes

Tags: css, wordpress, footer, overlap, visual-composer

Pages made with Visual Composer is overlapped over the footer of existing wordpress themes.

My site url is: [mo-on.co.kr](https://mo-on.co.kr)

Especially Visual Composers` WooCommerce products seem to overlap themselves in mobile and overlap the bottom section on desktop.

Could you help me keep my homepage from overlapping with footer?

Best,
Jeil

Comment: did you set min-height?

Comment: No, I didn`t not set min-height.
But I solved it the way Tushar Kumawat commented!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Please add CSS:
```

.woocommerce {display: inline-block;}

Comment: Welcome, Jeil !!